# Prisma select query with DateTime in UTC and data type being timestamp without time zone

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma, prisma-graphql

DB: PostgreSQL

My table structure:

```
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_seq'::regclass),
    user_first_active_at timestamp(3) without time zone,
    created_at timestamp(3) without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at timestamp(3) without time zone NOT NULL
```

The field `user_first_active_at` **is saved in DB as UTC.**

I am trying to fetch the results via raw Prisma query

```
// currentDate is new Date() - 2 Days
const users = this.prisma.$queryRaw<User[]>`
      SELECT id::INTEGER 
        FROM  users WHERE 
        user_first_active_at >= ${currentDate} // current date param is passed as 2022-10-28 05:00:00.000 UTC
```

Consider the UTC Time is `2022-10-28 05:00:00.000 UTC` and my DB state

Sample records in DB

```
ID |  user_first_active_at      | created_at                 | updated_at
1  | 2022-10-25 18:59:00.000 | 2022-10-12 11:40:37.268942 | 2022-10-12 11:40:37.268942
2  | 2022-10-25 19:00:01.000 | 2022-10-12 11:40:37.268942 | 2022-10-12 11:40:37.268942
```

The query would fetch the Row2.

However my expectation is query should not pick any result as `user_first_active_at + 2 days` > Current UTC i.e `2022-10-28 05:00:00.000 UTC`

Looks like Prisma is converting `user_first_active_at` again to UTC.

Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: If `currentDate` is on 2022-10-28 and `user_first_active_at` is on 2022-10-25 I don't see how a timezone issue could cause that behavior.

Comment: @some-user If current date time is `2022-10-28 05:00:00.000 UTC`, and user was first at `2022-10-25 19:00:01.000` then the query should not return this row as `2022-10-25 19:00:01.000` + 48 hours is less than `2022-10-28 05:00:00.000 UTC`

Comment: Can you try enabling logging and checking what date value is sent to the database?
You can log the query params which are sent to the database. Here's a reference on how you can configure logging: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/logging#event-based-logging